# Explicit homotopy that takes antipodal map to a map with fixed point

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

[homotopic maps from the sphere to the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103329/homotopic-maps-from-the-sphere-to-the-sphere)

The link above gives a very intuitive way to show that the result in question holds but could someone give me please the explicit homotopy he is using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homotopy is 
$$H(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n;t) = (r\cos(t\pi+\alpha),r\sin(t\pi+\alpha),-x_3,\dots,-x_n),$$
where $(r,\alpha)$ is the standard polar coordinates of the point $(x_1,x_2)$, i.e,
$$x_1=r\cos(\alpha),\, x_2=r\sin(\alpha).$$

It's obvious that 
$$H(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n;0) = (x_1,x_2,-x_3,\dots, -x_n),$$
and 
$$H(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n;1)= (-x_1,-x_2,-x_3,\dots, -x_n).$$
I leave you to find the fix point(s) of $H(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n;0)$.